# text books or online courses for a math student to learn asset pricing

Tags: portfolio-optimization

I just got my bachelor degree in math and statistics and will take a mathematical finance master degree. I have not learned any financial courses and want to teach myself asset pricing. I have seen many people recommend Asset Pricing by Cochrane. What are text books and online courses that make me prepared for reading Asset Pricing by Cochrane?

Comment: I am not sure why this question was considered to be "career advice" by those who voted to close. Asset Pricing theory is a legitimate academic field, and the answers given here seem helpful and on point.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do better than Cochrane.  His lectures can be found starting here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAXSVuGaw0KxTEN_cy-RCuEzzRdnF_xtx

Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

For empirical work, i highly recommend [Bali/Engle/Murray (2016)](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Empirical+Asset+Pricing:+The+Cross+Section+of+Stock+Returns-p-9781118095041), discussing portfolios sorts, Fama/MacBeth regressions and several "capital market anomalies" like Beta, Size, Value, Momentum, Idiosyncratic volatility, etc.

All content is based on the U.S. CRISP/Compustat dataset, discussed in a separat chapter.